# How do I parse through a command to receive a specific line with a child process in Node JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, linux, terminal

I am trying to get the diskspace of a vm using a child process on node js. This is my code:

```
const { exec } = require('child_process');


function diskSpace(err, result) {
   exec('df -h',(error, stdout, stderr) => {
     if (error) {
       console.error(`exec error: ${error}`);
       return;
     }
     console.log(`stdout: ${stdout}`);
     console.log(`stderr: ${stderr}`);
})};

diskSpace();
```

When I receive  run this using node stats.js, which is the name of my file I get the out of the df -h command on my terminal. I want to parse through this info and only get the info for /dev/disk/1:
[node stats.js][1]

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2vzb1.png but I dont know how. help ?

Answer (score 0):

Well, you are doing that all correct. The callback function is executed on the child [process termination](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_exec_command_options_callback), so stdout is actually a string:

```
const { exec } = require('child_process');
function diskSpace(err, result) {
   exec('df -h',(error, stdout, stderr) => {
     if (error) {
       console.error(`exec error: ${error}`);
       return;
     }
     console.log(`stdout: ${stdout}`);
     console.log(`stderr: ${stderr}`);
     console.log('>>', /(\/dev\/disk1.*)\/\n/.exec(stdout)[1]);
})};

diskSpace();
```